# Is the Sphinx beta okay to use in production?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I'm having to recompile Sphinx ([thanks to this issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/186362/mysql-error-cant-find-symbol-mysql-plugin-interface-version-in-library) – if you can help I'd be impressed!).

**Is the Sphinx beta ready for use in a production environment?**

I know that Sphinx 0.9.9 has been feature-frozen for a long time, and the Sphinx beta has a number of really wonderful features. **But beta is scary**.

**Do I have anything to worry about?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this page: http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads.html

It said:

```
Note that 'beta' only applies to new features (RT indexes etc), 
everything else is stable.
```

I also use beta in production for more than a year, without any problem.

Comment: I'd seen that somewhere but couldn't remember where or the wording. Thanks for reminding me!