# What new Sphinx features are considered to be in beta?

Tags: mysql, sql, plugins, search-engine, sphinx

This is a follow-up question to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834465/is-the-sphinx-beta-okay-to-use-in-production)**.

Sphinx mentions on the downloads page:

```
Note that 'beta' only applies to new features (RT indexes etc),
everything else is stable.
```

**What is the "etc" in the new features?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the list of changes in 1.10b [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#rel110)